# How to create a graphic canvas in pure c to display graphic figures without any libraries and platform independent

Tags: c, canvas, graphics

I think it must be possible to create a graphics library without any other library.

Just to draw circles and triangles and rectangles with basic math. If so, where is the point how to make the "drawable area"?

Is it possible to draw to screen in pure C or is assembly required?

Comment: platform independent and without libraries are mutually exclusive here, so you will have to decide on one or the other. Each system has its own way of putting bitmaps on the screen. You would have to rasterize your circles/triangles/rectangles to bit maps and call the on the system to create a  window and draw the bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Graphics programming is inherently platform dependent. Let's say, for the sake of argument, there were only two operating systems: linux and windows. You can use platform specific functions on both of them, to create windows and draw something. For your application to be "platform independent" in this context would mean to detect which OS you are running on (say, using preprocessor defines at compile time) and use different system calls based on that. However, this gets really messy, really fast.

It gets even worse when you're talking about 3D (or hardware accelerated 2D), because different graphics cards again behave differently. So, again, even if there were only two graphics cards (plus the two operating systems), you're already at four different cases for the same basic operation of, say, drawing a circle inside a window.

Can you do it?

Technically, yes. But graphics libraries exist precisely because most people wouldn't want to.

What i would personally recommend, if you don't want to rely to heavily on third party libraries, is to use OpenGL. Yes, it's a library, but it comes preinstalled on most systems.

If you actually want to create your own platform independent graphics library, i would suggest to get comfortable using the existing ones first, just to get a feel for what is involved in making something like that work.